# 'Killed' and Close When Installing Packages in R

Tags: r, ubuntu

Using R in terminal in Ubuntu 14.04, I am simply trying to install packages. My command is:

```
install.packages("plyr", repos='http://watson.nci.nih.gov/cran_mirror/')
```

I've tried this with just `install.packages("plyr")` as well, and selected the appropriate mirror from the pop-up. However, in both instances i get this result:

```
    > install.packages("plyr")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Killed
root@[removed]/usr/local/lib/R/site-library#
```

I can't figure out why 'killed' is returned, and R closes.

I've looked around SO and Google but have not yet found an answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A menu should appear, something like:  "--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---"  Does that happen?  And how did you reply?  Or might some firewall on your end be preventing a connection?

Comment: Yep, I do receive that window and I select the appropriate mirror (USA-MD), then there's a short delay and then the 'killed' and R

Comment: That mirror works for me.  You might try a different mirror anyway, but I don't really expect that to help.  Could there be some firewall on your network, or your computer, or perhaps some lack of privileges for your logged in user on your machine?  What operating system are you running?

Comment: Yeh could be a good idea - I'll give that a shot. I just upgraded Ubuntu to 14.04 running on a virtual box on top of Windows 7 - just testing a few things out before getting a new laptop. This issue is fairly new - it worked earlier in the week on 14.04 then just stopped.

Comment: Just going back through some old questions - it doesn't matter at this point, but i don't understand how this is a duplicate of the posted 'duplicate' link - its not at all what happened.